# how to plot multiple data from .dat file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a multiple coloum data in latex using pgfplots. I have tried to get the graph but I am unable to plot the graph. My code is as follows and how can I add legends? Please guide me.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{pistonkinetics.dat}
m0_FEED, AT 773.15K, AT 823.15K, AT 873.15K, AT 923.15K, AT 973.15K
0.005, 1.30E+04, 12959.71536,12959.71536,12959.71536,12959.71536
0.007, 1.81E+04, 18145.78478,18145.78478,18145.78478,18145.784
0.009, 2.33E+04, 23333.9541,23333.9541,23333.9541,23333.9541
0.011, 2.85E+04, 28524.71381,28524.71381,28524.71381,28524.71381
0.013, 3.37E+04, 33718.48576,33718.48576,33718.48576,33718.48576
0.015, 3.89E+04, 38915.61947,38915.61947,38915.61947,38915.61947
0.017, 4.41E+04, 44116.39602,44116.39603,44116.39603,44116.39603
0.019, 4.93E+04, 49321.02848,49321.02848,49321.02878,49321.02849
0.021, 5.45E+04, 54529.67237,54529.67238,54529.67238,54529.67238
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{mydata.dat}{\mydata}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[minor tick num=1,
xlabel=Degrees, ylabel = temperature]
\addplot [black,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 773.15K}] {\mydata};
\legend{AT773.15K}
\addplot [red,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 823.15K}] {\mydata};
\legend{AT773.15K}
\addplot [blue,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 873.15K}] {\mydata};
\legend{AT873.15K}
\addplot [green,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 923.15K}] {\mydata};
\legend{AT923.15K}
\addplot [dashed,yellow,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 973.15K}] {\mydata};
\legend{AT973.15K}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Regarding your example, in the `filecontents` you've used the filename `pistonkinetics.dat`, but when you read in the data, you've used `mydata.dat`. I assume they should be equal. Second, `pgfplotstable` assumes whitespace-delimited columns, you need `\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mydata.dat}{\mydata}` when you use comma. For legends: either `\legend{a,b,c}`, or `\addlegendentry{a} \addlegendentry{b} \addlegendentry{c}`

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplotstable` assumes whitespace-delimited columns, when you have comma as a column delimiter you need to specify it:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mydata.dat}{\mydata}
```

For legends: either

```
\legend{a,b,c}
```

or multiple instances of `\addlegendentry`, e.g.

```
\addlegendentry{a}
\addlegendentry{b}
\addlegendentry{c}
```

I'd also recommend having `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` in the preamble, if you don't have a `compat=<some higher version number>` already. The obvious benefit is that the ylabel gets a better placement.

[image: output of the code below]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
m0_FEED, AT 773.15K, AT 823.15K, AT 873.15K, AT 923.15K, AT 973.15K
0.005, 1.30E+04, 12959.71536,12959.71536,12959.71536,12959.71536
0.007, 1.81E+04, 18145.78478,18145.78478,18145.78478,18145.784
0.009, 2.33E+04, 23333.9541,23333.9541,23333.9541,23333.9541
0.011, 2.85E+04, 28524.71381,28524.71381,28524.71381,28524.71381
0.013, 3.37E+04, 33718.48576,33718.48576,33718.48576,33718.48576
0.015, 3.89E+04, 38915.61947,38915.61947,38915.61947,38915.61947
0.017, 4.41E+04, 44116.39602,44116.39603,44116.39603,44116.39603
0.019, 4.93E+04, 49321.02848,49321.02848,49321.02878,49321.02849
0.021, 5.45E+04, 54529.67237,54529.67238,54529.67238,54529.67238
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mydata.dat}{\mydata}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  minor tick num=1,
  xlabel=Degrees,
  ylabel = temperature
  ]
\addplot [black,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 773.15K}] {\mydata};
\addlegendentry{AT773.15K}
\addplot [red,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 823.15K}] {\mydata};
\addlegendentry{AT823.15K}
\addplot [blue,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 873.15K}] {\mydata};
\addlegendentry{AT873.15K}
\addplot [green,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 923.15K}] {\mydata};
\addlegendentry{AT923.15K}
\addplot [dashed,yellow,very thick] table [x={m0_FEED}, y={AT 973.15K}] {\mydata};
\addlegendentry{AT973.15K}

% for the legend entries you can alternatively use
% \legend{AT773.15K, AT823.15K, AT873.15K, AT923.15K, AT973.15K}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have posted a real answer instead of the comment in the first place.